# Lipschitz constant of L2 reg. logistic regression $\sum_i \log \left(1 + \exp\left\{ -t_i \left(w^T x_i\right)\right\} \right) + \mu \|w \|_2^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let the L2 regularized logistic regression function is given by,
\begin{align}
f(w) &= \frac{1}{N} \sum_i \log \left(1 + \exp\left\{ -t_i \left(w^T x_i\right)\right\} \right) + \mu \|w \|_2^2 \ = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i f_i(w),
\end{align}
where $t_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $w, x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\mu  \in \mathbb{R}$, and $f_i(w) := \log \left(1 + \exp\left\{ -t_i \left(w^T x_i\right)\right\} \right) + \mu \|w \|_2^2$ .

**Questions**:

- How would/could I find the (small) Lipschitz constant $M$ and $\nu$-strongly  parameter of $f(w)$?
- How can I find the (small) Lipschitz constant $L$ of $\nabla f(w)$ and $L_i$ of $\nabla f_i(w)$?

---

I am sorry if this question has already been asked or it is trivial to compute (analytically?).